# Angular 2, How to display current route name? (router 3.0.0-beta.1)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I want to display the name of the route in the `app.component.html` template. I'm looking for a simple solution, something that can be written like this:

```
{{router.currentRoute.name}}
```

My current router config:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/catalog',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'catalog',
        name: 'Catalog', // Is this property deprecated?
        component: CatalogComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'summary',
        name: 'Summary',
        component: SummaryComponent
    }
];
```

Comment: There are no route names in the new router.

Comment: So if I want to display route name I have to code my own solution?

Comment: The `data` parameter could be used for that. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterConfig-type-alias.html

Comment: Is this proper usage? `{path: 'catalog', data: 'Test data for catalog', component: CatalogComponent}` + `import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';` +  `constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {this.route = this._route;}` + `log() {console.log(this.route);};`. I can't find the test data string in the object outputed by the console. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I don't have time just yet but something along https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your routes are configured with your route name in the data property like this:

```
{
    path: 'somepath',
    component: SomeComponent,
    data: {
        name: 'My Route Name'
    }
}
```

In your `app.component.ts` you can `import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';` + `import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';` and do the following:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe(event => {
      let currentRoute = this.route.root;
      while (currentRoute.children[0] !== undefined) {
        currentRoute = currentRoute.children[0];
      }
      console.log(currentRoute.snapshot.data);
    })
}
```

This will listen for `NavigationEnd` events and then traverse down to the current route so that you can access the `data` of that route.

If you are on `/somepage` using the code above, it should print `{ name="My Route Name"}` in your console.

Comment: `TypeError: this.router.events.filter is not a function`

Comment: Don't forget to `import` the `filter` function from `rxjs`

Answer (score 0):

````
constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute, 
private router: Router
) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.router.events.pipe(
 .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(event => {
   let currentRoute = this.route.root;
   while (currentRoute.children[0] !== undefined) {
     currentRoute = currentRoute.children[0];
   }
   console.log(currentRoute.snapshot.data);
 });
}```


 try this if anybody facing issue with filter
````